# Is there a way to make amazon refund an incorrect charge?

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection

1. Amazon (US) has charged me incorrectly (shipment cost was calculated incorrectly), but the support refuses to refund with money, it only offers "promotional credit" that can be used on next purchases.
   I do not plan to use amazon again as their level of service is very low and there are errors in their IT systems. Is there a law that obliges them to refund?
2. They sent the package to an incorrect address. I chose the correct address in the interface but somehow at their back end a different address was chosen.
   They refuse to change the address after the shipment has been sent. There's no way to get the package at that address, and it is not my error. Is there a law that they should send the package to the correct address even if I found out that the address is incorrect after the order had been shipped as I had paid for the package already.
3. Should they somehow compensate for the time that was wasted on their incompetent support specialists? (Approximately 6 hours of useless conversations and repeating the same issue again and again)
4. What is the legal way to ask a company for a compensation without applying to court, when the support specialists say "there's nothing we can do, the system does not allow us to compensate"?

I'm worried if it is legal to mention a specific store and if they can sue me for mentioning them. Just in case the info I gave is only for example, it may not be 100% accurate, it is only for the purpose of making an inquiry here, in fact the info I provided may be not 100% true. And maybe it is about a different store.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @Ron Beyer, I mentioned that it was Amazon US.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what your basis is for saying that they calculated shipping incorrectly. Every experience that I have had has involved a definite shipping charge which is part of the price that you have to agree to – I have never encountered a case of "plus shipping, we'll charge you separately for shipping". You may disagree with their shipping and handling charge, but that does not constitute an error on third part.

You are also stuck with the shipping address at the point of the agreement: you can't change your mind and have it shipped elsewhere (at least, legally – tactically it is possible if you act immediately). Again, it is not clear what evidence you have that the address they have is their error. For the sake of argument, I will assume that somehow their server put some random address into the shipping field at the very last minute, even though you typed it in correctly and they displayed that shipping address at the confirmation page. If that is the case and they did truly ship your package to random oblivion, they have a responsibility to deliver it to the address that you actually agreed to. The challenge will be to convince them, or the court, that the address that you think you entered is indeed what you entered.

You are not charged for customer service, and they will not compensate you for the time you spend disputing the charge and shipment.

The remedy available to you depends in part on whether you are directly buying from Amazon, or through a third party. This does not include going to court, instead you will resolve your dispute with binding arbitration.

Comment: Yes, you pointed it out correctly, there's no proof, as this is how their IT system works.

Comment: There's a way to prove that the shipment cost was calculated incorrectly - as there's a help page with the description how it should be calculated. But it is very hard to find a support specialist who understands the problem and it takes too many hours to find a person which can compare the help page and the cart.

Comment: I tried to ask them before making an order, and no one was able to answer why the shipment cost is different from the description in help pages, but then they promised to surely correct the charge after the order is made. Then I made the order and different support people told me that they do not know what others promised, and that they are not going to make a refund. The real problem seems to be the unqualified personnel.

Comment: For the address, there definitely was an error in the site interface, but there's no way to prove that I chose a different address. This is the problem with IT systems, there's no way to prove that it was not me but an error.